# While instaling Buildozer for kivy i had an error saing "zipp is missing"

Tags: python, installation, kivy, buildozer

It's been several times that I try to install Buildozer to convert my kivy application to APK.

I use a version of Linux from the Window Store.

After downloading all the dependencies,

I launch the install of Buildozer with the command: sudo python 
setup.py install

And I get an error.

I follow this method: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-1.0.1.dev0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for buildozer==1.0.1.dev0
Searching for zipp>=0.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipp/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/8c/2c5f7dc1b418f659d36c04dec9446612fc7b45c8095cc7369dd772513055/zipp-3.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=c599e4d75c98f6798c509911d08a22e6c021d074469042177c8c86fb92eefd96
Best match: zipp 3.1.0
Processing zipp-3.1.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-7EAeC9/zipp-3.1.0/setup.cfg
Running zipp-3.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-7EAeC9/zipp-3.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-EWghGG
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zipp.py", line 217
    def open(self, mode='r', *args, pwd=None, **kwargs):
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
Moving zipp-0.0.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
zipp 0.0.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
error: The 'zipp>=0.4' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-resourcese
```

I managed to install zipp independently but the error is still there

If i do :  pip3 list

i get :

```
appdirs (1.4.3)
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
attrs (17.4.0)
Automat (0.6.0)
blinker (1.4)
certifi (2018.1.18)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
cloud-init (19.4)
colorama (0.3.7)
command-not-found (0.3)
configobj (5.0.6)
constantly (15.1.0)
cryptography (2.1.4)
Cython (0.29.16)
distlib (0.3.0)
distro-info (0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1)
docutils (0.16)
filelock (3.0.12)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
hyperlink (17.3.1)
idna (2.6)
importlib-metadata (1.6.0)
importlib-resources (1.4.0)
incremental (16.10.1)
Jinja2 (2.10)
jsonpatch (1.16)
jsonpointer (1.10)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
keyring (10.6.0)
keyrings.alt (3.0)
Kivy (1.11.1)
Kivy-Garden (0.1.4)
language-selector (0.1)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
netifaces (0.10.4)
oauthlib (2.0.6)
PAM (0.4.2)
pexpect (4.8.0)
pip (9.0.1)
ptyprocess (0.6.0)
pyasn1 (0.4.2)
pyasn1-modules (0.2.1)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
Pygments (2.6.1)
pygobject (3.26.1)
PyJWT (1.5.3)
pyOpenSSL (17.5.0)
pyserial (3.4)
python-apt (1.6.5+ubuntu0.2)
python-debian (0.1.32)
pyxdg (0.25)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.18.4)
requests-unixsocket (0.1.5)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
sh (1.12.14)
six (1.14.0)
ssh-import-id (5.7)
systemd-python (234)
Twisted (17.9.0)
ufw (0.36)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
urllib3 (1.22)
virtualenv (20.0.17)
wheel (0.30.0)
zipp (3.1.0)
zope.interface (4.3.2)
```

Comment: Are you using `pip` in one place and `pip3` in another? What does `pip -V` return, and what does `pip3 -V` return?

Comment: I think it's what happened, because of successfully install it with python3

Answer (score 0):

> Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-1.0.1.dev0-py2.7.egg

It looks like you've installed buildozer for python2, whereas you only checked for the zipp module in your python3 environment.

Comment: Yes indeed, I did not install them with the same version of python.
Thank you for answering

Answer (score -1):

If find the solution,
if i install buildozer with pyhton 3

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```